# Return just the value of an xpath - Nokogiri Ruby

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I'm using xpath to get some values on a website like this

```
auction_page = Nokogiri::HTML open(a, "User-Agent" => theagent)
auction_links = auction_page.xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "near")]/@src')
```

Which returns what I need like this

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fcd7bef5730 name="src" value="http://thevalue.com">
```

I just want to get the value, not the value or anything else. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `.text` method.

So `auction_links.text` should return "http://thevalue.com".

**Edit:**

If that doesn't work try, `auction_links.first` which will return an array, I'm sure the link will be inside there. ; )

For further reference, here is a great tutorial for [basic Nokogiri Crawling/Parsing](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/).

Comment: Hey - interesting enough both answers work, I'll accept in 2 minutes when I'm allowed. However, - .first only would work for me if I remove the /@src and then pick it out as the 7th value in the node, which i don't know how to do. It's not .7 .7th or .seventh. Any thoughts?

Comment: .text is what I needed though

Comment: you would get the `x`th value from an array with `[]`-brackets. Note to count `x-1` as the Array starts counting from 0.

Comment: That was a pretty silly question TheChamp, apologies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as below:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-end
<a id = "foo" class="bar baz" href = "www.test.com"> click here </a>
end

doc.at_xpath("//a[contains(@class,'bar')]/@href").to_s
# => "www.test.com"
```

So in your case you can write:

```
auction_page.at_xpath('//iframe[contains(@src, "near")]/@src').to_s
# => "http://thevalue.com"
```